# No manda los datos que quiero ver ¿mala estructuración o lógica?

Tags: java

Tengo este código **main**(tengo declarado el `static CRegistro list = new CRegistro();`)

```
public static void main(String[] args){

      CRegistro otr = new CRegistro();

    int op=0;

      do{

    op = menu();

    switch(op){

        case 1:
            añadir(otr);
            break;

        case 2:
            break;
    }
      }while(op!=2);

          }
```

en el método *añadir* tengo esto

```
public static void añadir(CRegistro nuevo){
        String nombre;
        int edad, saldo, retirar, renta;
        String sexo;
        try {
            System.out.print("nombre: ");
            nombre = leer.nextLine();
            leer.nextLine();

            System.out.print("edad: ");
            edad = leer.nextInt();

            System.out.print("sexo(h/m): ");
            sexo = leer.nextLine();
            leer.nextLine();

            System.out.print("saldo actual: ");
            saldo = leer.nextInt();

            System.out.print("retirar: ");
            retirar = leer.nextInt();

            System.out.print("renta que se le cobrará: ");
            renta = leer.nextInt();

            System.out.println();
          list.añadir(new CRegistro(nombre,edad,sexo,saldo,retirar,renta));

        } catch (Exception e) {}

    }
```

al finalizar, quiero ver los datos que tengo con esto

```
for(int i=0; i<list.lista.size(); i++){
            System.out.println(list.lista.get(i).obtenerNombre());
            System.out.println(list.lista.get(i).obtenerEdad());
            System.out.println(list.lista.get(i).obtenerSaldo());
            System.out.println("--------corte---------");
        }
```

**el problema es aquí** cuando quiero ver los datos me da los *saldo* y *edad* pero no me trae el nombre. ¿será mala estructuración? Tengo 5 clases, todas con herencia(excepto la de Test donde está el *main*) por práctica.

me trae a pantalla:

```
//campo vacío donde debería ir el nombre pero lo pongo para entendimiento
20 //refiriéndose a la edad
1000 //refiriéndose al saldo
---------corte------
//campo vacío
30
2000
----corte-------
```

en la parte de `list.añadir(new CRegistro(nombre,edad,sexo,saldo,retirar,renta));`

tengo esta clase

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class CRegistro extends CMantener{

    ArrayList<CMantener> lista = new ArrayList<CMantener>();

    public CRegistro(String nombre, int edad, String sexo, int saldo, int retirar, int renta){
       asignarNombre(nombre);
       asignarEdad(edad);
       asignarSexo(sexo);
       asignarSaldo(saldo);
       retiro(retirar);
       asignarRenta(renta);
    }

    public CRegistro(){}

    public void añadir(CRegistro nuevo){
        lista.add(nuevo);
    }
}
```

¿algún consejo para traer los datos completos? ¿por qué no me los manda?
Es una práctica.

Comment: Deberías mostrar también el método `asignarNombre`.

Comment: @Error404 
Solo es esto:
public void asignarNombre(String nombre){
     this.nombre = nombre;
 }

Comment: Pon el metodo obtenerNombre

Comment: Otra cosa a las variables no las asignes en base a un método,es mas rápido asignarlas directo.

Comment: Las tengo declaradas _private_

Comment: declara en `public` esas variables,es mas fácil el acceso(sin creación de métodos extras).

Comment: @HectorSeguro eso no resuelve el problema ni ayuda a la revisión. Un debugger puede mostrar los valores aunque las variables sean privadas.

Comment: Me parece que se están perdiendo datos al usar `Scanner#nextInt`

Comment: @HectorSeguro los dos comentarios que has puesto son malas prácticas de programación desde mi punto de vista. Siempre es mejor asignar con métodos pues puedes tener un mayor control de lo que va a suceder en esa asignación y sobretodo, declarar `public` una variable es exponerla demasiado cuando no hace falta.

Comment: @JoseLuis Tienes algunos errores en el código que debes pulir. El método `añadir(CRegistro nuevo)` recibe un parámetro que luego no usa para nada porque instancias un objeto nuevo con los datos que lees que es el que añades a la lista finalmente. Corrígelo. Por otra parte tiene la lista que tienes no es de la clase `CRegistro` es de la clase `CMantener` ¿Ésta clase tiene la variable nombre y los getter y setter implementados?

Comment: he intentado lo que me han dicho, y sí, como dice @LuiggiMendoza, se pierde información, al correr el registro, ingreso el nombre y justo después veo lo qué contiene la variable _nombre_ con un `System.out.printl(nombre);` y es un campo vacío. Intenté lo que dice @Darth vader de hacer los _parseInt_ pero me sigue dando campo vacío. Ahora estoy viendo eso, ¿alguna sugerencia?

Comment: @Awes0meM4n Es cierto, ya corregí eso, pero sigue igual.

Comment: Voté tu pregunta como duplicada. Revisa las respuestas de esa pregunta, para mí la respuesta aceptada te explica muy bien la causa del problema y la solución correcta usando `Scanner`.

Answer (score 0):

Esto es porque el método nextInt no lee el último carácter de nueva línea de entrada y es leída en la siguiente llamada de nextLine, entonces cambie los leer.nextInt() por Integer.parseInt(leer.nextLine())

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A continuación te pongo el código modificado:

```
public static void añadir(CRegistro nuevo){
    String nombre;
    int edad, saldo, retirar, renta;
    String sexo;

    try {
        System.out.print("nombre: ");
        nombre = leer.nextLine();
        leer.nextLine();

        System.out.print("edad: ");
        edad = Integer.parseInt(leeropciones.nextLine());

        System.out.print("sexo(h/m): ");
        sexo = leer.nextLine();
        leer.nextLine();

        System.out.print("saldo actual: ");
        saldo = Integer.parseInt(leeropciones.nextLine());

        System.out.print("retirar: ");
        retirar = Integer.parseInt(leeropciones.nextLine());

        System.out.print("renta que se le cobrará: ");
        renta = Integer.parseInt(leeropciones.nextLine());

        System.out.println();
        list.añadir(new CRegistro(nombre,edad,sexo,saldo,retirar,renta));

    } catch (Exception e) {

    }
}


public static int menu(){

    int opcion = 0;
    try {
        System.out.println("1 .- añadir ");
        System.out.println("2 .- salir ");
        opcion = Integer.parseInt(leeropciones.nextLine());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return opcion;
}
```

Esto es del sitio en inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo

**Notas:**

-Procura hacer esto para tus DTO's (Data Transfer Object) como
    CMantener(esto lo haces fácil con entornos de desarrollo como Eclipse o Netbeans):

```
private String nombre;

public String getNombre() {
    return nombre;
}

public void setNombre(String nombre) {
    this.nombre = nombre;
}
```

-También asegúrate de cerrar tus instancias de Scanner.

Comment: Al usar así el `Scanner` pierde todo sentido. Mejor usa `BufferedReader`.

Answer (score 0):

He encontrado la solución, es tan burda, tan absurda que hasta me dio pena quitarles su tiempo por esta pregunta, fue tan simple como poner un `leer.nextLine();` justo al principio

[image: justo después del <code>try{</code>]

no sé cómo ni por qué funciona de esta manera, estuve haciendo a prueba y error: moviendo el orden de ingreso a las variables, y la primera que estaba hasta arriba, al principio(o a la cabeza) daba este error, lo solucioné así.
Si alguien sabe por qué pasa esto se lo agradecería que compartiera el por qué.